# APIM and AKS integration

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-aks, vnet, azure-nsg

I am trying to integrate APIM(External) to the VNet where AKS is running. right now, I have created /29 CIDR subnet where AKS subnet is there and assigned to the APIM but APIM keep complaining that port 3443 is blocked. I have specifically added the rule to allow 3443 as mentioned in the troubleshooting steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-common-network-configuration-issues to NSG assigned to the subnet, but still it throws the error? can someone help me how to troubleshoot further?

NSG Rule for subnet -> Inbound

```
> priority- 102, Name - Port_3443, port - 3443, protocol - TCP, Source -
> ApiManagement, Destination - VirtualNetwork, Action - Allow
```

Update:
I have removed NSG from the subnet where APIM is, still its showing the same issue

Comment: Did you open 80 / 443 outbound to the AKS subnet and there particularly open inbound coming from APIM subnet?

Comment: actually I don't have any NSG assigned to the APIM subnet which means its wide open right?. I am wondering is there any thing I can check from the Vnet perspective. apart from this I don't have an option to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

From the document, you need to deploy the APIM instance in a dedicated subnet that does not contains other resources.

> When deploying an Azure API Management instance to a Resource Manager
> VNET, the service must be in a dedicated subnet that contains no other
> resources except for Azure API Management instances. If an attempt is
> made to deploy an Azure API Management instance to a Resource Manager
> VNET subnet that contains other resources, the deployment will fail.

You could deploy an AKS in a different subnet in that VNet that APIM instance exists. If there is no NSG assigned, it means wide open to or from that VNet.

You can get more references at https://blog.baeke.info/2019/06/10/azure-api-management-and-azure-kubernetes-service/

Comment: Yes, I have a dedicated subnet for the APIM instance with no NSG rules. still I am getting the error.

Comment: Do you mean the dedicated subnet with no rules or no NSG assigned? If you have set an NSG, you should add rules for port 3443. Are there any NSG rules assigned to the AKS subnet?

Comment: Yeah, that's what confusing. we have multiple subnets in the same Vnet. I have created one subnet dedicated for APIM and there is other subnet for AKS which has NSG assigned to it but there are no rules to allow 3443 port. My understanding from the documentation is we need to add the ports only to APIM subnet if there is a NSG right? or we need to open the port in all the subnet belongs to VNET when APIM is part of ?

Comment: What you understood is right. You need to add the ports only to APIM subnet if there is an NSG. However, it depends on different scenario, you need to add different ports. Could you show the specific error message and when and how it will display?